# asp.net scriptmanager javascript file order

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I have a master page with a script manager which loads JQuery automatically (it's a Sitefinity project by the way). This is all fine.

Then I have a user control which uses the ScriptManagerProxy to load scripts specific to this control. Problem is that for some reason the JQuery file is being loaded after the user control's files.

I would have thought that the master page ScriptManager would load its scripts then load scripts specified by Proxies in user controls.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hook into the document loaded event to process your scripts to ensure all necessary js libraries/html are fully sent to the browsers.

You can use jQuery(document).ready or form.load event to solve your problem.

Ref link: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: the idea is to eventually use composite scripts to reduce the massive amount of files being downloaded so keeping it in the script manager would be a plus.